# Ways to exclude a word in a regex (without lookahead?)

Tags: regex

If I have the input:

```
hello cat
hellocat
hello gat
```

I would like to find the a line that starts with the word "hello" and doesn't have the word "cat" after it.

Is it possible to negate a group, for example:

```
hello[^(\s?cat)]
```

Or are you only able to negate a set of characters in that position? If not, what are some ways to accomplish this? The only way that I've been able to do this is with a positive lookahead:

```
hello(?!\s?cat)
```

But I was wondering if there were alternative approaches to doing this.

Comment: It's a negative lookahead, but I think it is the way to go for your use case.

Comment: Well, I would think you're just going to need to do some extra steps. First build a regex that matches lines that start with hello followed by cat - then remove all those matches. Then you can look for any lines starting with `hello` and not have to worry about it being followed by `cat` since you already removed them. Negative/Positive lookaheads are helpful for a reason.

Comment: Is this an academic question or is this something seeking implementation?

Comment: @AER -- thanks for your answer below -- that's really interesting! This is more just to see alternative approaches for this. First, I would probably use a programming language with a simple string contains/ternary expression if it was anything more advanced then a simple "cat" in it. Then, if in regex I would use the lookahead. So this question is more to explore possible ways of approaching a regex problem to get the correct solution (knowing the "simplest" of the correct solutions is obviously the lookahead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible easily without using the negative lookahead.

You can exclude specific characters using the `[^abc]` convention. However you'd have to explicitly exclude cat but then permit everything that is almost cat.

E.g.

```
((hello)ca[^t]|(hello)c[^a]|(hello)[^c])
```

Then get the captured group within corresponding to the `hello` group. The spaces after the hello and making that an option make it a bit harder. This optional space can be captured with the following:

```
((hello)\sca[^t]|(hello)\sc[^a]|(hello)\s[^c]|(hello)ca[^t]|(hello)c[^a]|(hello)[^c ])
```

NB: It has all six options, and the final one adds an optional space to ensure that the first three don't get captured.

Tested here: https://regex101.com/r/sgoHyJ/1

I guess you can see why they invented negative look-aheads...

Comment: ...I think it's too early in the morning for me. Didn't think this through...You're absolutely right.

Comment: I did find though an error that the added spaces were causing though!

Comment: Very challenging question

Comment: Absolutely. Lookaheads are definitely the right tool for the job.

Comment: Updated to account for the space being captured as not c, nasty...

Answer (score 4):

There is also another way without look arounds which I think is worth mentioning as an interesting concept: `/hello(?:\scat)|(hello\s.*)/`

In this case we first match what we don't want (but don't capture it) then we only capture the second part if first part failed, which means that in the capture you will always have something that does not contain `cat`.

You can check in this example https://regex101.com/r/bydCGb/3, in the match information box, the "group 1" capture - and also check the substitution part - we never have the cat part.

According to your case, you can then say: if there are capturing group 1 then do something.

Answer (score 2):

You *can't* easily do this with pure regex without using a negative lookahead.  However, if you are making these regex calls via an API in some programming language, you could phrase a match using the following positive:

```
^hello\b.*
```

and the following negative:

```
^hello cat\b
```

That is, a valid match is positive on the first pattern and negative on the second pattern.  In Java, this proposed solution would look like this:

```
String input = "hello gat";
if (input.matches("hello\\b.*") && !input.matches("hello cat\\b.*")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

Comment: The only decent solution for me. I suppose 2 layers of filtering will be required then. At least my problem is solved